# Do I need to screen share so that they can see my Bitcoin Wallet is genuine?

Tags: trading, fraud

An online trader (Brokerz) has called me saying they are closing down and are refunding everyone's money via Bitcoin.  I have a BC Wallet but they are saying they need to screen share to see if it is genuinely my wallet so that they are refunding the money to the right person.  This sounds like a scam - has anyone else had something similar?  I did trade with this company, and frankly thought I had lost the money due to a scam so are they just coming back for a second bite of the cherry?

Comment: Definitely strange. I don't see why a screen share would be any more proof than just providing an address. I also don't know how this would benefit them if it was a scam though. I'd be very cautious.

Comment: From a quick search it seems you are not the only one who believes to have been scammed by this company. Be careful not to inadvertently give out any sensitive information to them, and whatever they say don't send them any more money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Do I need to screen share so that they can see my Bitcoin Wallet is genuine?**

No.

If a genuine person was concerned about paying to the wrong address, they just need to read out over the phone the address you gave them and have you confirm it is correct.

---

A genuine business that is closing down is much more likely to send you a message saying something like you have 30 days to withdraw your money from your account. Either that or leave the whole matter to insolvency administrators.

---

In this case the persons contacting you are obviously trying to use a false prospect of return of money to tempt you into giving them access to a computer on which you keep your private keys that will give them the means to steal your remaining money and plant malware that will steal future money.

The only sensible approach, I believe, is to break off contact with criminals. You have nothing to gain by giving criminals more access to your financial data. Don't give confidence tricksters endless opportunities to persuade you that something stupid is sensible - that's what they are good at.